# What is the advantages of using sendmsg, recvmsg

Tags: sockets

I'm studying Linux network programming and see some function about reading, writing data from/to socket. recv, send, recvmsg, sendmesg. As far as I know, recvmsg can be used to pass file descriptor, adding timeout for reading/writing from/to a socket. Could you let me know is there any more advantage of using recvmsg, sendmsg over recv, send?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

A few things recvmsg and sendmsg can do:

1. You can do scatter/gather buffers. For example, let's day you want to receive exactly 1MB of data, but you only have 10 buffers that are each 100KB, then you can fill up each in a single recvmsg call.
2. Access to Control flags, ancillary data, and IP packet header fields. For example, for UDP, you can get the destination IP/port address that the packet was addressed by enumerating the control data (with certain ioctls enabled) returned from recvmsg.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but another useful feature of recvmsg is for protocol using header/data format in packets. You can set a buffer for receiving the header, and another buffer for receiving the data.

The latter just need to be shifted by received data so far and you'll get continuous data without any (additional) memory copy. It's more efficient.

Imagine the case where you need to transfer a very large file in parts. With classical recv call, you'll need to create a buffer like this (pseudo code):

```
while(received < expectedFileSize)
{
  char buffer[65536 - sizeof(Header)];
  int s = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); // One syscall here
  received += write(outfd, &buffer[sizeof(Header)], s);  // One syscall per buffer, which cause a memcpy in the kernel
}
```

With recvmsg, you can skip a memory copy per packet and many syscall:

```
char * file = mmap(...); // Get a writable buffer for this file
while(received < expectedFileSize)
{
    char header[sizeof(Header)];
    struct iovec v[2] = { { header, sizeof(Header) }, { file + received, expectedFileSize - received } };
    msghdr msg = { NULL, 0, v, 2, 0, 0, 0 };
    int s = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0); // Only one syscall here
    received += s - sizeof(Header);
}
```

Unfortunately, this can only work for fixed size header.

Reciprocally, imagine you need to write a HTTP server.

This protocol sends a bunch of headers before sending the content. Using sendmsg is almost a 1:1 way to perform this task, where one thread is compiling the headers while another thread is compiling the content.

There is no need to add locking in that case, since each thread performs on its own buffer, **and** the processing of content compilation does not need to wait for headers to be entirely compiled (since without `sendmsg` you would need the headers size to append your content **after** the headers).